# Adding exceptions to regexp patern in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, markdown, ruby-2.0

I wrote this regexp to convert a string into an HTML tag. It matches `[img foo]` and a third optional (*left* or *right*) argument at the end. For example,`[img foo left]`.

```
/\[img (\S+)(\sleft|\sright)?\]/
```

But it also matches these tags inside markdown inline code and code blocks. So

`````
````
  [img foo] # matches, but should not (it's inside a markdown code block
````
`[img foo]` # matches but should not match (inline code)
`````

I'm having the same problem with fetching references. Here is the full method:

```
  def custom_image_tag(text)

    # look for image tag
    text.gsub(/\[img (\S+)(\sleft|\sright)?\]/) do
      id, css = $1, $2

      # check is second argument is a link
      # if yes use it in image tag
      if id =~ /http(s)?:\/\//
        image_tag id.strip, class: css

      # if no search doc to see if its value matches a reference
      # For example, [img foo] will match "[foo]: whatever.com"
      else
        text.match(/\[(#{id})\]: (.*)/) do |match|  # Same issue here
          image_tag match[2].strip, class: css
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I wonder, is there a way to add an exception, or add an escape sequence? Best way to solve this?

Here's a Rubular playground: http://rubular.com/r/b9ClAE6Rhj

Comment: I guess best way to solve this (since you asked) isn't the way with regular expressions. Monkey-patch your Markdown gem with code for your custom tag, not just search & replace all occurences of it.

Comment: I am. I'm writing an extension for redcarpet.

Comment: So just peek how it's done there. I bet other tags aren't rendered when put in code block. You need to replicate the same behaviour for your custom tag.

Comment: If you were doing this from scratch, I'd recommend a Parsing Expression Grammar like [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) or [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/) or Citrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you match the quotes with priority over the tag, then you can avoid matching the tags within quotes.

````
quoted = /(?=```[^`]*```|`[^`]*`)/m
tagged = /\[img (\S+)(\sleft|\sright)?\]/
text.gsub(Regexp.union(quoted, tagged)) do
  if $1 then "" else
    ...
  end
end
````

Or, if you want to avoid the regex becoming complicated, then you should use `StringScanner`. With it, you can put each piece of regex in a `(els)if` condition under separate cases.

Comment: Thanks. That really complicates the code. I wonder if it's better adding an escape sequence... so... look for an escape character at the begging of the sequence... wouldn't that be simpler? `/(some escape character here)\[img (\S+)(\sleft|\sright)?\]/`

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton It is the same. I just extracted that part and did it in two steps to demonstrate. If you want, you can create the regex in one step.

Comment: I see, thanks. I will give this a try. One last thing. I tried to modify this `/\[img (\S+)(\sleft|\sright)?\]/` so that the begging of the string has to be `[img` by adding `\A`, so it became `\A\[img (\S+)(\sleft|\sright)?\]` but that stops matching the third option argument...